# Getting reference error: "invalid count value"

Tags: referenceerror

I'm getting "invalid count value" with this block of code and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
pad(string, length) {
  if(length < string.length) {
    return string;
  }
  const startPaddingLength = Math.floor(length - string.length / 2);
  const endPaddingLength = length - string.length - startPaddingLength;
  const paddedString = ' '.repeat(startPaddingLength) + string + ' '.repeat(endPaddingLength);
  return paddedString;
}
```

This piece of code is written exactly the way my course tutorial shows it should be. It works in the video walk through but not when I test it in my console. I have tried using MDN to research this type of error message, but wasn't really finding anything to lead me in the right direction.

What can I try next?

Comment: What language is this? (Please tag the question with the right language).

Comment: With the error, do you get a stack trace? If so, please add that to the question, in a code block. If not, let readers know what line number the error occurs on. Your compiler or run-time should tell you.

Comment: How are you calling the function, what's your sample data? Please add that into the code sample.